# How can I arrange multichoice-field items alphabetically?

Tags: python, django

I have a multichoice-field in my forms in which names of various staffs are populated. I want these names to appear in an alphabetic order, they are populated in a random order currently.

Answer (score 0):

In your `models.py` you need to set the ordering in the `Meta` class of your staff class.

For example, assuming this is your class:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = [u'name']
```